# Fetching Signin and SignOut time from clerk

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, fetch, clerk

I want to fetch sign-in and sign-out time from clerk. If there is anyone who knows how to do it or if there is any functions do let me know.

```
const Timesheet = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("Time Sheet");
  const clerk = useClerk();
  const [signInTime, setSignInTime] = useState(null);
  const [signOutTime, setSignOutTime] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserSignInSignOutTime = async () => {
      const userSignInSignOutData = await fetchSignInSignOutTimeFromServer(clerk.user.id);
      setSignInTime(userSignInSignOutData.signIn);
      setSignOutTime(userSignInSignOutData.signOut);
    };

    fetchUserSignInSignOutTime();
  }, [clerk.user.id]);
```

i tried this way but it says look for actual function from clerk